# Caught IOError while rendering: 'No such file or directory' Error when trying to view images

Tags: python, django, pinax

I'm getting the error above when trying to display thumbnails of larger images. Full size images work fine.

Here is the code for the image definitions in the models.py file.

```
    def _get_thumb_url(self, folder, size):
        """ get a thumbnail giver a folder and a size. """
        if not self.coverart:
            return '#'
        upload_to = path.dirname(self.coverart.path)
        tiny = path.join(upload_to, folder, path.basename(self.coverart.path))
        tiny = path.normpath(tiny)
        if not path.exists(tiny):
            import Image
            im = Image.open(self.coverart.path)
            im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
            im.save(tiny, 'JPEG')
        return path.join(path.dirname(self.coverart.url), folder, path.basename(self.coverart.path))

    def get_thumb_url(self):
        return self._get_thumb_url('thumb_100_100', (100,100))

    def thumb(self):
        """ Get thumb <a>. """
        link = self.get_thumb_url()
        if link is None:
            return '<a href="#" target="_blank">NO IMAGE</a>'
        else:
            return '<img src=%s />' % (link)
    thumb.allow_tags = True

    def fullpicture(self):
        """ Get full picture <a>. """
        link = "%s%s" % (settings.MEDIA_URL, self.coverart)
        if link is None:
            return '<a href="#" target="_blank">NO IMAGE</a>'
        else:
            return '<img src=%s />' % (link)
    thumb.allow_tags = True
```

Here is the line that causes me trouble in my template file:

```
<div class="coverart" >{{ spmodel.thumb|safe }}</div>
```

If I change it to this instead, the image displays fine (obviously not a thumbnail though which is what I want):

```
<div class="coverart" >{{ sp.fullpicture|safe }}</div>
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think `im.save` doesn't create directories if they don't exist. It's better to create empty file with desired path, open it and then save your image to it.